# Implementing call screening service

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm trying to implement a call screening service in my app. It seems the `CallScreeningService` class has really a bad design however. The abstract method `onScreenCall` is called on UI thread and it's not possible to use something different, in addition the method `respondToCall` must be called in `onScreenCall` because it's not possible to go async looking at AOSP source code. The code calls `recycle()` on `onScreenCall` arguments when it returns. The question: how is it supposed to work? We can't bind another service, we can't use an `AsyncTask`, even a load from database would be a problem since the access is performed on UI thread. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjava or coroutines to access your data in background thread

Comment: you can't, at the time onScreenCall returns you can't do anything more.

Comment: I'm using rxjava inside the onscreencall to query database and making retrofit call and its working fine. You should edit the question and show your code.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling respondToCall() inside the onScreenCall after I got the result from my repository

Comment: Ok, so you are still in onScreenCall waiting for the response in a blocking call.

Comment: Its not a blocking call. I'm using rxjava with background threads. Anyway, onscreencall is in ui thread because all android services start on ui thread.